# How to optimize repeated Regex extractions in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, regex, performance, google-bigquery

My table has around 17 million rows of news articles, summing to around 40 GB of data. I have a list of about 120 keywords and want to extract their occurrences plus surrounding context within all the articles.

So my regular expression part would look like this:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(LOWER(body), ".{1,50}\\bKEYWORD\\b.{1,50}"
```

where *KEYWORD* is replaced by the real keyword and *body* is the full-text of the article.

What would be the best strategy to perform these queries for all the 120 keywords, aggregating the results into one destination table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH keywords AS (
  SELECT LOWER(keyword) AS keyword
  FROM UNNEST(['Car', 'Vehicle', 'Motorcycle']) keyword
)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(LOWER(body), keywords_regexp) AS mentions, body 
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
(SELECT CONCAT(r'.{1,50}\b(?:', STRING_AGG(keyword, '|'), r')\b.{1,50}') AS keywords_regexp FROM keywords)
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(body, keywords_regexp)
```

You can test, play with above using some dummy or public data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT text AS body
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
), keywords AS (
  SELECT LOWER(keyword) AS keyword
  FROM UNNEST(['Car', 'Vehicle', 'Motorcycle']) keyword
)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(LOWER(body), keywords_regexp) AS mentions, body 
FROM `project.dataset.table`, 
(SELECT CONCAT(r'.{1,50}\b(?:', STRING_AGG(keyword, '|'), r')\b.{1,50}') AS keywords_regexp FROM keywords)
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(body, keywords_regexp)
-- LIMIT 100
```

> **UPDATE**: Optimized version - took just 17-20 sec vs. 440-460 sec for above version

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT text AS body
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.comments`
), keywords AS (
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(r'\b', LOWER(keyword), r'\b') AS keyword_test,
    CONCAT(r'.{1,50}\b', LOWER(keyword), r'\b.{1,50}') AS keyword
  FROM UNNEST(['Car', 'Vehicle', 'Motorcycle']) keyword
)
SELECT ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(mention) AS mentions, body
FROM (
  SELECT body, REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(LOWER(body), keyword) AS mention
  FROM (
    SELECT keyword, body 
    FROM `project.dataset.table`, keywords 
    WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(body, keyword_test) 
  )
)
GROUP BY body
```

> Per OP's request - Some explanations on  what makes the difference :o)

In initial version - there was naive straightforward approach of building regexp expression with all keywords and apply extract all row-by-row which obviously quite expensive (performance wise)

So, optimized version first extract qualified keywords for each workflow - using just keywords w/o wrapping 50 chars on each side. so in that first "round" we collect pairs of keyword and row where body contains the keyword. so if body has N keywords - we are getting N rows with keyword, body.
Then, each such row gets processed by full regex with given qualified keyword only. This ends up being much-much cheaper! 
So, final action is just to assemble back(group by) rows with same body and aggregate initial extracts - but because initial extract could be arrays by themselves - we use not just `ARRAY_AGG` but rather `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG` function

Hope this helps to understand how above optimized version works and why it works better :o)

Comment: I tried your solution today, but apparently it ran much longer then my initial solution (which was writing out all the regular expressions in the query and putting them together in some STRUCT construction. Your query is much easier to read, though. My first try was taking 25 minutes to complete, your solution did not complete even after an hour. Not sure why exactly, I would need to investigate further

Comment: yes, agree - "easier" to read and maintain code in this case quite affects the performance - even for the relatively simple example of 3 keywords and 8.4M rows - it took almost 8 minutes to process. Looks like I was more focused on direction to go with and did not pay attention to optimization aspect in favor of keeping code small and compact. So, I came up with optimized version - see update in my answer very shortly - good news - it took just 20 seconds for same 3 keywords and 8.4M M rows

Comment: I can confirm your optimized query performs much better. Big thanks, Mikhail! Though, if you don't mind, could you explain what makes the difference? Curious to learn more about that

Comment: @HenningLebbäus - sure, will get back to you with some explanations later in a day :o)

Comment: @HenningLebbäus - see update in my answer  - added "Some explanations on what makes the difference"

Comment: @HenningLebbäus - just wanted to follow up - did you have chance to see my explanation? does it make sense for you now?