# How to optimize repeated regex using cross join in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have about 20 million rows text data and want to label it based on several keywords (about 100k keywords). My text data was look like this

| text |
| --- |
| my car was broken |
| nobody knows |
| the fish is so beautiful |

While the keywords is look like this

| keywords |
| --- |
| car |
| beautiful |
| know |
| journey |

My expected output is look like this, where I will regex the text column using keywords data.

| text | keywords |
| --- | --- |
| my car was broken | car |
| nobody knows | know |
| the fish is so beautiful | beautiful |

I use regex like in [solution of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59195875/how-to-optimize-repeated-regex-extractions-in-google-bigquery)
But, since my data is so huge (20mio x 100k keywords) it runs so long like forever. So, what I want to ask is, is there any better solution?

Anyway, here the query I use:

```
 select 'my car was broken' as text
 union all
 select 'nobody knows'
 union all
 select 'the fish is so beautiful'
 )
 ,raw_keywords as(
  select 'car' as keyword
  union all
  select 'beautiful'
  union all
  select 'know'
  union all
  select 'journey'
  )
  SELECT  text, keyword
    FROM raw_text, raw_keywords 
    WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, keyword)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following  query returns what you want spliting the text into words and doing a `INNER JOIN` on the keywords table, without having to create a new table.

```sql
WITH splited AS (
  SELECT SPLIT(text, ' ') AS text_split, text FROM project.dataset.text_tab 
)

SELECT text, keyword
FROM (
  SELECT text, word_inside FROM splited, UNNEST(text_split) AS word_inside
)
INNER JOIN
  `project.dataset.keywords`
ON
  keyword = word_inside;
```

- Tables:

[image] [image]

- Result:

[image]

Comment: Any solution for multi-words search? What if my key words is "long car". Now I need better way to split my text.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test with a big dataset, but a solution can be:

- Extract all words and save it in a temporary table (use clustering to improve the performance of the join)
- Join this temporary table with the keyboard table

**So this is the code:**

First create the temporary table:

```sql
create table word_text(
    word STRING,
    text STRING
)
CLUSTER BY word
;
```

Populate it *(here I didn't test with a big amount of data, so maybe this step can be a bit long)*:

```sql
insert into word_text
-- Transform array to rows
select word, text from(
    -- Transform text to array
    select split(text, ' ') as words, text from (
        select 'my car was broken' as text
        union all
        select 'nobody knows'
        union all
        select 'the fish is so beautiful'
    )
 ),
UNNEST(words) word
```

[image]

Cross the data:

```sql
SELECT word_text.text, raw_keywords.keyword
FROM word_text, raw_keywords 
WHERE word_text.word = raw_keywords.keyword
```